# Lua: Print value from nested table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I feel like this is a really silly question...

```
t = {
a = {x,y},
b = {z},
}
```

How do I print the first value of the key 'a'? ("x")
Neither

```
print(t["a"][1])
```

nor

```
print(t.a[1])
```

does it, so how would I go about?

What's the difference between '[]' and '.' btw?

Comment: In Lua string literals must be enclosed in quotes: `t = {a = {'x','y'}, b = {'z'}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code, `x`, `y`, and `z` are all undefined and so `t.a` and `t.b` are empty tables. My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16278877/107090) to your previous question stores `x`, `y`, and `z` as strings (but as *keys*, not as values).

Comment: and so it was a silly question. I got it to work, I thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

> What's the difference between '[]' and '.' btw?

The dot is just a shortcut / syntax sugar for the index operator [] with strings.
`foo.bar` is equivalent to `foo["bar"]`. `foo[bar]` on the other hand would return the value at the index of the value of the variable `bar`, so if `bar` happens to be `baz` it would do `foo["baz"]` / `foo.baz`.

You must use the `[]`-syntax when using strings which are no valid Lua identifiers ("variable names") or non-strings as indices, like `foo["Jon Doe"]` or `foo[3]`.